# Custom time field not visible in process builder

Tags: process-builder, custom-field, contact

I would post my question to the Salesforce community but I am unable to login there for the last couple of days for an unknown reason.

Today I create to near-identical custom fields on the contact object in my sandbox. One was a datetime field and the other a time field. Both have the same security and view/edit permissions.

The first immediately became visible to the process builder to be used in a field update action. The second just doesn't appear. Typing in the entry box doesn't bring it up either.

I've confirmed I have picked the correct object to update, as I have already selected other contact object fields to be updated in the same workflow.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were on a non SFSE board for a second. We'll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this is a limitation of time fields. See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5:

> Be aware of the following limitations when using a time field type. The time field:
>
> - Cannot be added to records in Automated flows created in Cloud Flow Designer or processes designed in Process Builder.
> - Is not supported in Schema Builder.
> - Doesn't support the creation of custom index for SOQL queries.
>     Is not available for standard lookup relationships in external objects.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

My real issue, then, is getting the time portion of event start datetime out into a separate field - does not have to be time, can be text. I've searched for a simple solution, and I'm happy to post a new question - unless you can point me at a solution.

Thank you again.

Comment: Can you use a formula field? The new Timevalue function sounds promising for what you want to do. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_using_date_datetime.htm

Comment: Thanks again - I think I've got what I needed now. A process basically copies the most recent event datetime to the contact record and a formula field extracts the time portion.